# How to make method calls to be in one worker thread java

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a class say MessageListener class. That has a method `startListening()` which listens on the Multicast IP and Port to receive message in an infinite loop:

```
public class MainClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        MessageListener listener = new MessageListener();
        listener.startListening(); // Started ONLY ONce for the entire application
    }
}

public class MessageListener implements MessageReceiver{
    public void startListening(MessageReceiver receiver) {
        new Thread("Worker thread") {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                while(true) {
                    //MulticastSocket receive - receives byte[]
                    messageReceived(byte[]);
                }

            }}).start();
    }

    public void messageReceived(byte[] data) { // Interface Method
        new Message().handleMessage(data);
    }

}

public class Message() {
    MessageHeader messageHeader;
    MessageBody messageBody;

    public void handleMessage(byte[]  data) {
        messageHeader = new MessageHeader();
        messageHeader.parseHeader(data); //subsequent messages interleave the thread here?
        //extract msgbody from data 
        messageBody = new MessageBody();
        messageBody.parseMessageBody(); //subsequent messages interleave the thread here?
    }
}
```

I have above structure of classes. `startListening()` is called ONLY once at the start of the application.  My assumption is the `startListening()` creates ONE worker thread (for the entire app) in addition to main thread and all the methods `messageReceived()`, `handleMessage()`, `parseHeader()`, and `parseMessageBody()` are all called in this one worker thread and hence these methods are entirely running in single worker thread and when new message arrives from the MulticastSocket, the methods starting from `messageReceived()` should run sequentially like a single threaded application.

But the method access is interleaving between the incoming messages. Say for instance, while first message is accessing `parseHeader()`, second message also accesses `parseHeader()`.

I could not sync everything into like one single worker thread access unless I make the method calls as “static synchronised” to make it lock on the class instance otherwise with object synchronisation, obviously the message would be having independent access with different objects.

Is there a way I can make this work like a Single worker thread access for one message till it completes or make the method access sequentially between methods without `static synchronized` method modifiers?

Comment: listener.startListening() how does this line compile for you?

Comment: @giorashc I am using framework, during start I call startListening(). For illustration purpose, I gave the code example here. You need to run MainClass

Comment: The situation you described should not be happening. You're working in a single thread context since the same thread that is receiving the data is also handling it. Either your code is not what you think (and your pseudocode is therefore wrong), or you think you're seeing something that's not actually happening.

Comment: agree with @Kayaman... unless there is something you omit from your framework code this is single threaded. Therefore unless some of the methods you call are asynchronous in nature, you should not run into more then 1 thread calling `parseHeader()`

Comment: What framework are you using?